# Is there a way to sort Lightroom images by 'edit' status?

Tags: software, lightroom, workflow, smart-collections

Usually my workflow involves 'picking/flagging' photos to edit and leaving the rest alone (RAW files that is).  However, sometimes I jump right in and start editing before rating/picking.  In that case is there a way to filter images based on whether they've been edited/cropped?  I haven't looked too hard, but nothing obvious stands out from the visible filtering options.  I appreciate any insights.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ditton on creating a Smart Collection, that's really the way to go. I'm wondering if "Has Adjustments" only applies to specific adjustments, i.e. will it catch if you just cropped the photo, for example? That's OK though, you can add the "Cropped" + "is true" rule to your collection.

You could also create a Smart Collection that will display recently edited photos. The rule could be "Edit Date" + "is today" or instead of "today" try "is in the last" + x + "days" (or "hours"). This can be combined with "Has Adjustments" of course.

Answer (score 5):

Create a smart collection based on "Has Adjustments" - that'll give you photos that have been edited.

Comment: can you limit this to a particular folder? I haven't used smart collections yet

Answer (score 2):

Using only "has adjustments" does not include photos which have been cropped.
So, also add "cropped" is true