# Is it possible to batch export all processed photos in Lightroom?

Tags: lightroom, batch, darktable, digikam, export

I want to stop using Lightroom and switch over to digiKam/darktable.

I have about 100,000 photos in one big Lightroom catalog. Most of these have never been processed.

However, I'd like to export all processed photos, so that I don't have to reprocess them in digiKam/darktable.

Is it possible to do this? Or am I going to have to go through my entire catalog and export them one at a time?

Comment: So if you have 5000 that you've done some processing on, you want to selectively export just those 5000 with adjustments?

Comment: Look through here: http://regex.info/blog/lightroom-goodies and see if any of those plugins (like data explorer) will let you select on the type of processing you did.  I am not posting as an answer as not sure they do what you need.  One issue is any raw images you import are "processed" already, but Lightroom does keep track of whether manual edits or presets are applied; you can filter on presets, but not sure about manual edits.  If you can select/collect them though, it is easy to export.

Comment: @MikeW -- yes, that's correct.

Comment: @Linwood -- thank you. I'll look at the plugins and report back if any of them work!

Comment: I don't know these specific programs, but another issue to take into account is that any tags you have assigned to pictures which are not stored in the pictures themselves (Exif ...) will probably be lost. AFAIK, there is no standard (RFC ...) for external picture metadata, so each program does it differently.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to sort Lightroom images by 'edit' status?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/4959/is-there-a-way-to-sort-lightroom-images-by-edit-status)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a smart collection with a "Has adjustments" set to "true" rule.

Then all of the processed photos will be in that collection and you will be able to export them at once.